# How to find script in HTML?

Tags: json, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retrieve the contents of the following tag and turn it into a json object:

```
<script type= "application/ld+json>contents</script>
```

I am trying to achieve this using BeatutifulSoup. However, the only results I obtain are when I use:

```
soup.find_all("script")
```

This returns a multitude of scripts on the webpage. However, I do not know how to access the one above. How would I achieve that? I have scanned the entire documentation, which did not guide me in the right direction.

Comment: `soup.find_all('script', type='application/ld+json')` ?

Comment: As your question contains a single line script, It wasn't that hard for you to double check whether there is any mistake you are making while pasting that portion. You forgot to input the trailing double quote just after  `+json` @wit221.

Comment: @Keyur Potdar Unfortunately, that returns a None object.

Comment: @SIM That was just to show the element I am looking for. The actual soup.find_all() call does not work.

Comment: Without the link to the page, I can't tell you anything more/different.

Comment: There is no reason for Keyur Potdar's suggested portion of code will fetch you none value: you perhaps couldn't apply it in the right way. What he has suggested is something like: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content="""
<script type= "application/ld+json">contents</script>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
for item in soup.find_all('script', type='application/ld+json'):
    print(item.text)`